# C# Threading with functions that return variables

Tags: c#, function

Okay so basically I have a function that returns a string, but to get that string it uses webrequest which means while it's doing that webrequest the form is locking up unless I put it in a different thread.

But I can't figure out a way to capture the returned data in a thread since it's started using thread.start and that's a void.

Any help please?

Current code if it matters to anyone:

```
string CreateReqThread(string UrlReq)
{
    System.Threading.Thread NewThread = new System.Threading.Thread(() => CreateReq(UrlReq));
    string ReturnedData = "";
    return ReturnedData;
}

string CreateReq(string url)
{
    try
    {
        WebRequest SendReq = WebRequest.Create(url);

        SendReq.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        SendReq.Proxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;                 //For closed port networks like colleges
        SendReq.Proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        SendReq.Timeout = 15000;

        System.IO.StreamReader Reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(SendReq.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
        string Response = Reader.ReadToEnd();
        Reader.Close();
        return Response;
    }
    catch (WebException e)
    {
        EBox(e.Message, "Unknown Error While Connecting");
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: This sounds like the perfect candidate for `aync/await`... have you considered reading about them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common means of doing this is to use a `Task<T>` instead of a thread:

```
Task<string> CreateReqThread(string UrlReq)
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew() => CreateReq(UrlReq));

    // In .NET 4.5, you can use (or better yet, reimplement using await/async directly)
    // return Task.Run(() => CreateReq(UrlReq));
}
```

You can then call `Task<T>.Result` to get the returned value (later), when it's needed, or schedule a *continuation* on the task which will run when it completes.

This could look something like:

```
var request = CreateReqThread(theUri);
request.ContinueWith(t =>
{
     // Shove results in a text box
     this.textBox.Text = t.Result;
}, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

This also works perfectly with the new `await`/`async` support in C# 5.